# How do remove the leading status id from a rails log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I wrote my own logger that writes a line as follows:

```
@my_log.info(message)
```

Where `message` would be something like:

```
{"action": "follow", "object": "Product"}.to_json
```

The log line leads with the word `INFO`, thereby making the line not pure JSON:

```
INFO -- : {"action":"follow","object":"Product"}
```

Is there a way to use the rails logging mechanism but leave off that leading log level so that the entire file will be json?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `formatter` method, from the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Format):

> You may change the date and time format via datetime_format=.
>
> ```
> logger.datetime_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
> # e.g. "2004-01-03 00:54:26"
> ```
>
> Or, you may change the overall format via the formatter= method.
>
> ```
> logger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
>   "#{datetime}: #{msg}\n"
> end
>
> # e.g. "2005-09-22 08:51:08 +0900: hello world"
> ```

That example should work *as is* for your case, since only `msg` is printed (well, and `datetime`, but i assume you'll want to keep that).